# Angular 6 - [ngModel] data value - Identifier name is not defined

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I am trying to add the data value to into an ngModel.

I have the data:

```
  data = [
    {
      name: 'SomeName'
    }
  ];
```

And then on my app.component.html:

```
<input type="email" name="name" class="form-control" [ngModel]="data.name">
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Identifier name is not defined. Array does not contain such a member.
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data should be an Object to bind to ngModel, change it as

```
 data = { name: 'SomeName' };
```

another way is to use the index , if you do not want to change the structure of data

```
<input type="email" name="name" class="form-control" [ngModel]="data[0].name">
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be something like:

```
<input type="email" name="name" class="form-control" [ngModel]="data[0].name">
```

You are trying to access the `name` property from an `Array`, you should reach to the `Object` containing that property. `(Array[index])`